# How to correctly implement wait_window()?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.button_height = 2
        self.button_width = 8

        self.list_of_tasks = []

        **#Other irrelevant code**

        #Button for adding a new task to current tab
        self.new_task = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, bg="yellow", height=self.button_height, width=self.button_width*2,
                                  text="New Task",  command=self.create_new_task)
        self.new_task.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="N"+"W"+"S"+"E")

        #Frame for holding all tasks in currently selected tab
        self.tasks_in_tab = tk.Frame(master, height=300, width=300)
        self.tasks_in_tab.grid(row=2, rowspan=5, column=0, columnspan=5)

    def create_new_task(self):
        #Creates a new task
        new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        entry_window = Task_Entry(new_window)

        entry_window.wait_window(entry_window)

        task = tk.Button(self.tasks_in_tab, text=entry_window.test_entry)
        self.list_of_tasks.append(task)
        task.pack()

class Task_Entry:
    #Window for entering data into a new window
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.test_entry_field = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.test_entry_field.pack()
        self.test_entry = self.test_entry_field.get()

        self.cancel_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Cancel", command=self.exit_program)
        self.cancel_button.pack()

    def exit_program(self):
        self.master.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
gui = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I am attempting to use Tkinter's `wait_window` function in my code, but I am unsure how to properly use it in the context of where I wish to implement it.

What is suppose to happen is the user clicks the `new_task` button, the function `create_new_task` is called. This then prompts a new window, as stored under the class `Task_Entry`, which contains an Entry field for the user to enter text into. As soon as the user enters their input the `Task_Entry` window is terminated, the user input - under the `test_entry` field of the called `Task_Entry` window class - is supposed to be passed to the new Button named `task`.

I am pretty sure I should be using `wait_window()` to freeze the `create_new_task` function until the user has submitted their input, but I have been unable to get its implementation correct.

In addition, I believe I am incorrectly retrieving the user's input from the `Task_Entry` class under `entry_window` with `get()` and `set()`. Any clarification would also be of tremendous help there as well.

Comment: Please provide a better [mcve], above code returns error(s).

Comment: Your code won't run. For exmaple, it depends on `self.buttons_frame`, which you never create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
entry_window.wait_window(entry_window)
```

with:

```
entry_window.test_entry_field.wait_window(entry_window.test_entry_field)
```

Because `wait_window` is a method for *widget* class objects, whereas `entry_window` is an object of `Task_Entry` which doesn't even inherit from a widget class. Which means there's no defined `wait_window` method for it. However, it has an attribute, `test_entry_field` which is a widget so there is a defined `wait_window` method for it.

---

As is, you use `get` too early in the code, it returns what's inside the entry in that very instant, which should be moved to right before destroying the entry, such as in callback for `"Cancel"` button:

```
def exit_program(self):
    self.test_entry = self.test_entry_field.get()
    self.master.destroy()
```

---

The code should be working the way you want it to when using the `"Cancel"` button:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.button_height = 2
        self.button_width = 8

        self.list_of_tasks = []

        #Other irrelevant code**

        #Button for adding a new task to current tab
        self.new_task = tk.Button(self.master, bg="yellow",
                                height=self.button_height,
                                width=self.button_width*2,
                                text="New Task",
                                command=self.create_new_task)
        self.new_task.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2,
                                sticky="N"+"W"+"S"+"E")

        #Frame for holding all tasks in currently selected tab
        self.tasks_in_tab = tk.Frame(master, height=300, width=300)
        self.tasks_in_tab.grid(row=2, rowspan=5, column=0, columnspan=5)

    def create_new_task(self):
        #Creates a new task
        new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        entry_window = Task_Entry(new_window)

        entry_window.test_entry_field.wait_window(entry_window.test_entry_field)

        task = tk.Button(self.tasks_in_tab, text=entry_window.test_entry)
        self.list_of_tasks.append(task)
        task.pack()

class Task_Entry:
    #Window for entering data into a new window
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.test_entry_field = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.test_entry_field.pack()

        self.cancel_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Cancel",
                                command=self.exit_program)
        self.cancel_button.pack()

    def exit_program(self):
        self.test_entry = self.test_entry_field.get()
        self.master.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
gui = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Also, note that you can't use `set` for an entry field itself, however, you can use `insert` or additionally you can assign a [variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) to the entry and then be able to use `set`.

Answer (score 0):

Wound up creating a few new functions to handle returning

```
def getBtn1(self):
    return self.btn1.get()
def getBtn2(self):
    return self.btn2.get()
def getBtn3(self):
    return self.btn3.get()


s = equipPopUp('Equipment Requested',staff,'N',ERI_Included='N')
s.start()
ERI = s.getBtn1()
RFRI = s.getBtn2()
rlm = s.getBtn3()
```